# How to expand the Connector of ORG Chart

Tags: highcharts, orgchart

I am working on org chart on highcharts. Want to make the connector little wider. highlighted the part which one i want to make little wider
[here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omL2j.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linkLineWidth` on a specific level.

```
levels: [..., {
  ...,
  linkLineWidth: 10
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L4ygked0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.linkLineWidth